# Magento 2 get 100 most recent orders?

Tags: magento2, orders, collection, sales-order

How can I get recent 100 orders in magento 2.Currently I am getting orders but those are coming from starting onwords.I want recently placed 100 orders only. Can you help me on this ? I am getting orders collection using this

```
$this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect('*')->setPageSize(200);
```

Comment: Add your code in question

Comment: Do I need to add complete code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get recent order with below code..

```
protected $_orderCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    .....
            \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
           .......
        ) {
    ...
    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    ........

}


public function getOrders()
{


        $ordercollection =$this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect(array('*'));
        $ordercollection->setOrder('entity_id','DESC');
        $ordercollection->setPageSize(100);
        $ordercollection->setCurPage(1);

    return $ordercollection;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Use below code:**

```
$collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->setOrder('entity_id','desc');
$collection->addFieldToSelect('*')->setPageSize(100);
```